# Can Mockito mock a method without specifying each argument matcher individually?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

Let's say I have some method with 5 arguments, like

```
public int foo(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4, int arg5) {
  //do something
}
```

When I mock it, I end up doing something to the effect of

```
Mockito.when(myClass.foo(anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt())).thenReturn(expectedResult);
//do stuff
Mockito.verify(myClass).foo(expectedArg1, expectedArg2, expectedArg3, expectedArg4, expectedArg5);
```

Is there a way of combining all the `anyInt()` matchers into something that's easier on the eyes? Something like `Collections.nCopies(5, anyInt());`

Answer (score 0):

It will always better refactoring your foo method's arguments. Use wrapper which contains all arguments it will not only make it easier on eyes in the testing section and also it will make your class structure clear. Regarding your request, it is not possible because you are using `myClass.foo(...)` method you have to specify arguments one by one.